# SIGSEGV error details and removal steps

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

for the question: http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/TWODOGS

i wrote the following program but on the inline judge codechef i am getting sigsegv error. I want to know specifically which instruction is creating this error in my program so that i try and remove that.
here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    int arr[n+1];
    for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++)
        arr[i]=n+1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int p=min(i+1,n-i);
        arr[a[i]]=min(arr[a[i]],p);
    }
    int time=n+1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int p=a[i];
        if(p!=k-p&&p<k)
            time=min(time,max(arr[p],arr[k-p]));
    }
    if(time==n+1)
        cout<<"-1";
    else
        cout<<time;
}
```

Comment: Well, what have you *tried*?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis isearched and found sigsegv error are caused due to bad memory allocations or maybe due to wrong pointer initialisations but i think my code is correct in these terms.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis and then i am using gcc compiler codeblocks on which the program is running smoothly but not on the online judge

Comment: `int arr[n+1];` Note that this (variable stack allocated array) is a GCC extension.

Answer (score 4):

Given sample input 2:

```
Sample Input 2:
5 5
2 4 9 2 5
```

You cannot do this

```
arr[a[i]]=min(arr[a[i]],p);
```

because when `i == 2`, `arr[a[i]]` will be evaluated as `arr[9]`, which is out of bounds and results modification of memory which you do not own, that is, undefined behavior. This is where your program is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have an easier time if your identifiers were more meaningful.  That said:

```
cin>>a[i];
....
arr[a[i]]=min(arr[a[i]],p);
```

You are indexing arr[] by user input.  If you are getting a segfault, it's best to put in asserts for these situations in case the assumption is invalid, something like:

```
assert(a[i] < n-1);
```

Next:

```
time=min(time,max(arr[p],arr[k-p]));
```

again, indexing array based on user input.  Add another assert to test that arr[p] and arr[k-p] are valid.

Finally, for this line:

```
if(p!=k-p&&p<k)
```

Did you mean:

```
if(p!=k-p&&p<n)
```

a is allocated based on n, not k.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the question carefully ,

```
   the element in a[i] <= 10 ^ 6 .
```

You have declared an array arr of size n+1 .

```
   Constraint on n :    n <= 500000
```

Also you are trying to access arr[ a[i] ] which may go beyond the limit of array arr.

```
     a[i] may be greater than  5 * 10^5 .
```

This is leading to segmentation fault error.